# Rounding up decimal in EditText

Tags: android, eclipse, math, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to figure out how to round up the total to two decimal places. The total is an EditText. I can't get it to narrow down to just two decimal places. What wrong with it? Thanks for your help.

```
public void macro() {
    caloriesTotal = Double.parseDouble(calories.getText().toString());
    total = (caloriesTotal * .20)/9;
    DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat ("###.##");
    round.format(total);
    carbsTotal = (caloriesTotal * .40)/4;
    proteinTotal = (caloriesTotal * .40)/4;       
    fat.setText(Double.toString(total));
    carbs.setText(Double.toString(carbsTotal));
    protein.setText(Double.toString(proteinTotal));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
fat.setText(Double.valueOf(round.format(total)));
```

When you convert any number upto N number of decimal digit then you need to store that value in any variable or directly show like as above i mentioned.

Comment: What your updated answer indicates? Is it just a copy of my answer? or anything different from my answer?

Comment: Thanks, I did figure it out. I will check yours out also. I used the code 'fat.setText(round.format(total));'

Answer (score 3):

Simply `format()` should do for you,

```
DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat ("###.##");
String formatted = round.format(double_value);
fat.setText(formatted);
```

Comment: You just put code without explanation . That is the Difference between my answer and your answer my dear friend.

Comment: Always post relevant code with relevant explanation . As You suggested to Others.

Comment: Well, your updated answer doesn't show any explanation. Rather just a copy of two lines from my answer.

Comment: Then what it this ? When you convert any number upto N number of decimal digit then you need to store that value in any variable or directly show like as above i mentioned.

Comment: I did figure it out and will try yours to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format("%.2f", d)`, your double will be rounded